# Ho to apply validation rule using directive Reactive form?

Tags: angular

I use the reactive forms in Angular.

```
<input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name">
```

How to apply validation rule (custom or default `Validators.required`) for this input using directive?

Comment: Why you want to add valdiator using directiive?

Comment: Because my form element it is a component `InputComponent` that accepts type, and validation rule

Comment: Can't you set validation rule inside FormControl Object?

Comment: Problem is that I can not specify type of element in formControlObject, formGroup, depends it I need to show component: inputComponent, SelectComponent, TextareaComponent, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many built-in directives that apply some built-in [Validators](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators):

- [RequiredValidator](https://angular.io/api/forms/RequiredValidator) directive applies `Validators.required` validator

  ```
  <input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name" required>
                                                        ^^^^^^^^
  ```
- [EmailValidator](https://angular.io/api/forms/EmailValidator) directive uses `Validators.email` validator

  ```
  <input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name" [email]="true">
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```
- [MinLengthValidator](https://angular.io/api/forms/MinLengthValidator) directive uses `Validators.minLength` validator

  ```
  <input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name" minlength="4">
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```
- [MaxLengthValidator](https://angular.io/api/forms/MaxLengthValidator) directive uses `Validators.maxLength` validator

  ```
  <input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name" maxlength="10">
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```
- [PatternValidator](https://angular.io/api/forms/PatternValidator) directive uses `Validators.pattern` validator

  ```
  <input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*">
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```

But you can also create your own custom directive to apply validation rule. You just need to implement [Validator](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validator) interface, e.g.

**ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[customValidator]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: CustomValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
class CustomValidatorDirective implements Validator {
  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors|null {
    return {'custom': true};
  }
}
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name" customValidator>
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can even use `@Input` property in order to customize logic inside validator

**ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[customValidator]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: CustomValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
class CustomValidatorDirective implements Validator {
  @Input() customValidator: string;

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors|null {
    return control.value !== this.customValidator ? {'notYurzui': true} : null;
  }
}
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name" customValidator="yurzui">
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If it is not enough for you and you want to validate asynchronously then you can create async equivalent of custom directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[customAsyncValidator]',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS,
    useExisting: CustomAsyncValidatorDirective,
    multi: true
  }]
})
class CustomAsyncValidatorDirective implements AsyncValidator {
  validate(control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors|null> {
    return of({'custom': true});
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for extended answer, how can I pass type of element form in formGroup. So, when I display element in templete I want to check if formControlType == 'number' then to show component `InputComponent` and the same for slect, textareas,checkbox and redio button

Comment: You can take a look at Angular guide like this https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form Just search for `<div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">`